# Delphi: Indy9 to Indy10 Migration: Using IdCustomHTTPServer & IdHTTPServer

Tags: delphi, indy

Is there a doc on how to migrate an indy9 solution to indy10?

We migrated our client pieces fine.

The server piece is actually a component we use (with sources) that uses:

```
  IdCustomHTTPServer,
  IdHTTPServer,
  IdTCPServer,
  IdThreadMgrPool,
```

Any hints/docs on how indy10 has rearranged itself would be v helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a doc on how to migrate an indy9 solution to indy10?

Not specifically, but IIRC there might be some pieces mentioned in the [online documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html).

> IdCustomHTTPServer,
>    IdHTTPServer,
>    IdTCPServer

Those exist in Indy 10.

> IdThreadMgrPool,

That, on the other hand, was replaced with a new `TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool` component.

> Any hints/docs on how indy10 has rearranged itself would be v helpful.

Some of the big changes are:

1. Most of the `TIdTCPConnection` methods were moved to the `TIdIOHandler` class.
2. the `TIdPeerThread` class was replaced with a new `TIdContext` class.
3. `TIdThreadMgr...` components were replaced with new `TIdSchedulerOfThread...` components.

If you are having particular problems with the migration, ask questions about it.

Comment: We got this done, partly by removing unused multi threaded aspects of the code. Thank you!